# Как сделать резиновый модуль с картинкой?

Tags: joomla, bootstrap

Joomla3 Bootstrap3

Помогите разобраться. В общем, хедер при масштабировании экрана масштабируется вместе с браузером, то есть при сужении браузера не появляется нижняя полоса прокрутки, но когда под этим хедером создаю модуль с картинкой, при сужении картинка не ужимается вместе с шапкой, и появляется нижний скрол. Как решить эту проблему? Нужно, чтобы картинка вместе с хедером сжималась и не появлялась полоса прокрутки.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 TopHeader">
<div class="visible-md.visible-lg">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 logo">
<?php if ($tmpl_logo) : ?>
<a href="/" ><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($tmpl_logo);?>" alt="MYLOGO"/></a>
<?php endif;?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="nav Topmenu">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="Topmenu" style="none" />
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="hidden-md.hidden-lg">

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 Promo">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="Promo" style="xhtml" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Как видно, мой модуль расположен в `container-fluid`, вот он: `<div class="col-md-12 Promo">`, вот хедер: `<div class="col-md-12 TopHeader">`. Они в одном контейнере, но почему хедер резиновый, а этот модуль нет?

Вообще на данный момент bootstrap 3-й версии, и джумла тоже, во 2-й версии такого не было. И еще момент: хедер хоть и сжимается вместе с окном браузера, но он начинает складываться пополам, и получается каша. Мне кажется, это из-за 3-й версии бутстрапа. Как в ней реализовать то, что мне нужно, чтобы шапка и модуль с картинкой просто уменьшались с размером окна браузера?

Comment: А куда добавить img-responsive, если я картинку добавляю в сам модуль в джумле? Мне нужно, чтобы модуль сам стал резиновый, а там картинка в нем или текст - это неважно.

Comment: В самом модуле добавил и получилось, спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Картинки в модуле могут быть без вёрстки под Bootstrap. Чтобы картинки были в нем резиновыми, надо им добавить класс **img-responsive** - и будет вам счастье.